# Why does my turtle onclick function not work in while loop?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Hello I was trying to make a gun animation using turtle in python. I have the first bit down but the while loop I'm using to animate it is not letting the onclick function work.

Here's my code:

```
import time
penup()
speed(0)
canvas = getscreen()
hideturtle()
bullet_x = 0

gun_color = input("Enter the color: ")

def draw_gun():
    #gun is a rectangle and a square
    
    
    #handle
    goto(-150, 0)
    pendown()
    begin_fill()
    color(gun_color)
    for i in range(4):
        forward(20)
        right(90)
    end_fill()
        
                
    
    #top of toy gun
    penup()
    goto(-60, 50)
    pendown()
    begin_fill()
    color(gun_color)
    for i in range(4):
        right(90)
        if (i + 1)%2 != 0:
            forward(50)
        else:
            forward(100)
        penup()
    end_fill()
    
def water_bullet():
    begin_fill()
    goto(-30, bullet_x)
    circle(30)
    color("deepskyblue")
    end_fill()
    
bullet_shot = False
    
def bullet_spawn(x,y):
    bullet_shot = True

canvas.onclick(bullet_spawn)

while(True):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    clear()
    bgcolor("#F5F5DC")
    draw_gun()
    if (bullet_shot == True):
        bullet_x = bullet_x + 1
        water_bullet()
```

Thanks for helping out

I tried making a gun with a water bullet and I couldn't find the documentation to solve the problem.

Comment: you forgot to `import turtle`...

Answer (score 1):

You've found the problem, your `while(True):` blocks the mouse event which is why it should never appear in an event-driven environment like turtle.

I see other issues with your code as well.  You should separate the bullets into a turtle of their own that you can move and clear independently of the gun.  You only initiate bullets, you never stop and clean up after them.  You're not using the `global` keyword where necessary, eg. in `bullet_spawn()` for `bullet_shot`.  You're doing more redrawing than necessary.  Below is my rework of your code that addresses the above:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def draw_gun():
    # gun is a rectangle and a square

    # handle
    gun.penup()
    gun.setx(-150)
    gun.pendown()

    gun.color(gun_color)
    gun.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(4):
        gun.forward(20)
        gun.right(90)

    gun.end_fill()

    # barrel
    gun.setx(-180)

    gun.begin_fill()

    for _ in range(2):
        gun.forward(100)
        gun.left(90)
        gun.forward(50)
        gun.left(90)

    gun.end_fill()

bullet_x = -30
bullet_shot = False

def water_bullet():
    global bullet_x, bullet_shot

    bullet_x += 1

    if bullet_x > 200:
        bullet_shot = False
        bullet.hideturtle()
        bullet_x = -30
    else:
        bullet.setx(bullet_x)

def bullet_spawn(x, y):
    global bullet_shot

    if not bullet_shot:
        bullet.setx(bullet_x)
        bullet.showturtle()
        bullet_shot = True

def animate():
    if bullet_shot:
        water_bullet()

    screen.update()
    screen.ontimer(animate)

gun_color = input("Enter the gun color: ")

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('#F5F5DC')
screen.tracer(False)

gun = Turtle()
gun.hideturtle()

bullet = Turtle()
bullet.hideturtle()
bullet.shape('circle')
bullet.shapesize(2.5)
bullet.penup()
bullet.sety(25)
bullet.color('deepskyblue')

draw_gun()

screen.onclick(bullet_spawn)

animate()

screen.mainloop()
```

See if this works roughly as you envisioned.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are missing the following code:

```
def bullet_spawn(x,y):
    bullet_shot = True

onscreenclick(bullet_spawn) # replace with 'canvas.onclick(bullet_spawn)'
```

[Turtle doc link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onscreenclick)